# changing UserAccount Name Using Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-7

How to change user account name using command prompt in win7? Maybe you tell me that it can be find easily by googling, but I searched and I did not find any working command.

Here is a command which seems to work, but unfortunately it is not working :(

```
wmic UserAccount where Name="OLDName" call Rename Name="NEWName"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it just be:

`wmic UserAccount where Name="OLDName" Rename "NEWName"`

Comment: It will say "No Instances available"

Comment: That is the dodgy error message to indicate the name wasn't found.

Comment: But everything OK with my Given Names and This is the reason why I wondered it is not working !

Comment: Just run `wmic useraccount get name` to check what the names are

Answer (score 1):

When I use this command line directly in PowerShell (Administrator), I got the following error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wmic useraccount where name="OLD" rename NEW
ERROR:
Description = Invalid query
```

But I called it successfully when I entered into `wmic`:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wmic
wmic:root\cli>useraccount where name="OLD" rename NEW
```